# spring JMS producer error: Session: Message send failed due to timeout waiting on broker enforced flow control

Tags: spring, jms, qpid

I use Spring JMS to send and receives messages with apache QPID.
I got this error message:

Session: Message send failed due to timeout waiting on broker enforced flow control

What cause it?  Is it due to queue exhausted?
Where could I config the flow control for queue?

Thanks.

Comment: Apache Qpid provides two Brokers products: the CPP Broker and the Qpid Broker for Java.  Which do you use?  What version?

Comment: Qpid Broker for Java

Answer (score 1):

The Qpid Broker for Java imposes flow control on Sessions sending messages when limits are breached.  Limits can be applied to a individual queue, an individual virtual host or the overall file system usage.

In default configuration, the overall file system utilisation limit is applied.  It will automatically impose flow control when it detects that disk utilisation the volume hosting `$QPID_WORK` exceeds 90%.

When limits are exceeded the Broker writes messages to the logs such as:

```
VHT-1006 Filesystem is over x% per cent full, enforcing flow control.
```

When the utilisation falls (because messages have been consumed), flow control is automatically relinquished and the producers may begin sending again.

```
VHT-1007 Filesystem is no longer over x% per cent full.
```

You can read more about this feature here:

https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-java-6.0.4/java-broker/book/Java-Broker-Runtime-Disk-Space-Management.html#Qpid-Producer-Flow-Control

https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-java-6.0.4/java-broker/book/Java-Broker-Appendix-Operation-Logging.html#Java-Broker-Appendix-Operation-Logging-Message-List-VirtualHost

Comment: In my case I am getting this error in my qpid.log "[FileSystemSpaceChecker[default]] [vh(/default)/ms(BDBMessageStore)] VHT-1006 : Filesystem is over 90 per cent full, enforcing flow control."
I configured default host with 20MB capacity but still getting the same. Pls let me know where(file) is it configured and how it calculates 90%?
I am using qpid broker for java.